# $a^2+b^2=0$ in a field F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm not really sure how to answer this question.  Prove or give a counterexample: If $F$ is a field and $a,b$ are in $F,$ then $a^2+b^2=0  \implies a=b=0$

Comment: In $\mathbb F_2$, $1+1=0$. In $\mathbb F_5$, $1+4=0$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: What happen if $F$ is the field of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the condition that F is an ordered field  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field, or otherwise you may end up with an issue like the one Azarel is describing.

Given that you have an ordered field $F$ , it follows that :

i) The subset $P \subset F $ of positive elements of $F$ are closed under both addition and under multiplication, i.e., if $x,y$ are in
$F$ , then so are $x+y$ and $xy$

ii)For $x$ in $F$ , $x^2:=xx$ is in $P$

iii) If $a \geq b$ and $c\geq d$ , then $a+c \geq b+d$

It then follows that each of $a^2$ and $b^2$ are in $P$, and so is their sum.

Now, we know $1$ is in $P$ , since $(-1)(-1)=1$ . So, if we were to have

one of $a >0$ or $b>0$ , then (by ii)) $a^2>0$ and $b^2>0$ , so that (by order properties ) $a^2+b^2>0 $ . It follows both $a,b$ must be $0$.

Comment: The condition suffices for the statement to be true, but it is not needed.

Comment: What are the least conditions; what condition(s) can we do without? The counter you gave of $1+1=0$ in $Z_2$ does not apply, because ordered fields cannot be finite, and so have no "torsion".

Comment: There are some fields of nonzero characteristic where $0$ is not sum of two nonzero squares.

Comment: Can you give an example, for ordered fields, please?

Comment: I do not understand. How am I going to give an example of an ordered field where the condition that it is ordered is not satisfied? Are you sure this is what you meant to ask?

Comment: O.K, I misread, I guess Azarel's $\mathbb C$ is a counterexample; I confused the fact that there is an ordering (that allows us to say $x>0$) with having an ordered field. What I meant to show in my post is that if you want to guarantee that $a^2+b^2=0$ implies, $a,b=0$ , then you need to have an ordered field.

Answer (score 0):

If F is the field of complex numbers, then $a$ could be $i$ and $b$ could be 1 and then

$i^2+1^2 = -1+1 = 0$